# java 8: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) on Netbean IDE

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java-8

I copied this code below from book to prepare for Java Certificate exam.  When compile on Netbeans IDE(jdk 1.8.0_144), I got the compiler error " inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) on Netbean IDE"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> ohMy = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears");
        Map<Integer, Optional<Character>> map = ohMy.collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        String::length,
                        Collectors.mapping(s -> s.charAt(0),
                        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));

        System.out.println(map); 
}
```

It's still compile on Eclipse, please explain what is wrong here?
I uploaded error detail here:

[image: error deatail]

Comment: Seems to be an inferrence glitch. It can be fixed by using `Collectors.<Character>minBy`. I have the same problem with IntelliJ (it sees the code as valid in the editor, but compiling it fails, using JDK 1.8.0_112)

Comment: it compiles fine for me too on IntelliJ

Comment: Did you take the screenshot using your smartphone?

Comment: Yes, I used smartphone to take this picture. What's wrong?

Comment: Does anyone care to report this to Oracle? Would be good to know if there's a good reason for rejecting this program, while Eclipse and IntelliJ validation seem to agree on accepting it. Additionally, seeing that an explicit type convinces also javac could be a hint that inference should succeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to help the compiler here as it's a type inference issue:

You can solve the problem by *explicitly* specifying the type for the `Comparator` or any of the `Collectors`.

- `Collectors.<Character>minBy()`
- `Comparator.<Character>naturalOrder()`
- `Collectors.mapping((String s) -> s.charAt(0)`

Comment: Thanks you for you helping, it worked with:  Collectors.minBy(Comparator.<Character>naturalOrder()))));

Comment: But perhaps, you actually want `Map<Integer, Character> map = ohMy.collect( Collectors.toMap(String::length, (String s) -> s.charAt(0), BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())));` instead of dealing with `Optional`s…